# Planet asset metadata different from search endpoint

Tags: google-earth, planet

I ingested some PlanetScope 4-band Analytic assets into Google Earth Engine. I'm noticing the metadata of each scene is different compared to what the search_endpoint.py script from the [Planet docs page](https://www.planet.com/docs/api-quickstart-examples/step-1-search/) returns. Are there some auxiliary metadata files somewhere/am I missing something?

Comment: Could you show the differences you see?

Comment: Here's the EE output [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4bc29e1553463ecd1101d6f7cc568b5b). It's labeled in the Console. The Planet API return I'm getting matches the exactly the search_endpoint.py example from the docs site [here](https://www.planet.com/docs/api-quickstart-examples/step-1-search/).

Comment: I should add that beyond interests in metadata attributes for sorting, etc I was also hoping to find some decent method for cloud masking Planet imagery in EE. I'm assuming the 'cloud_cover' attribute is in regards to the entire scene though? Most of the standard cloud masking functions in EE are Landsat based. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not able to see the metadata in the GEE link. It might be tied to not being logged in as your user. I see this error message: `Image.load: Image asset 'users/bawong/mtr_hobet_mine/20160827_133756_0c82_PSScene4Band_analytic' not found.
    in <global>, line 5`. Could you post what you see in the original question?

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I just the ImageCollection public so you should be able to see it now. But here is what I see in GEE:

Comment: {
  "type": "Image",
  "bands": [
    {
      "id": "b1",
      "data_type": {
        "type": "PixelType",
        "precision": "double",
        "min": 0,
        "max": 65535
      },
      "crs": "EPSG:4326",
      "crs_transform": [
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0
      ]
    }

Comment: Sorry It was too long for comments but the metadata just repeats for bands 2-4 same as above in b1

Comment: I think the answer is simply that Planet's canonical metadata is not being reflected when the data is exposed in GEE. Perhaps there's another function besides `getInfo()` to show metadata? Unfortunately, I can provide the answer only from the Planet side not GEE.

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into it a bit more, but the 'getInfo()' or just 'print()' will get all metadata associated. If you remove the commented out section for the L7, you'll see all 190+ properties. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Also, are you aware of best cloud masking methods to process Planet assets?

Comment: I should have mentioned before that each Planet .tiff file also has an associated .json file that GEE can read. There are also XML metadata files but I'd guess GEE is less likely to support those.

Comment: Okay, I'm seeing from the [Planet product specs](https://www.planet.com/products/satellite-imagery/files/Planet_Imagery_Product_Specs.pdf) doc that the XML file is a separate asset, which I can get for each image and parse to match for ingesting into GEE. That said, the "cloud_cover" ratio attribute is nice, but at the end of the day I need to either compute a cloud score or use a cloud mask. The udm product looks to be what I need. I read somewhere it used to be the 5th band on the PS 4-band product. I'm not seeing so in my downloads though. Is that a recent change or any chance it will be?

Comment: A long time ago there were alpha masks in some 4-band products but they were not the same as the UDM, which differentiates between the various types of "bad" pixels: cloudy, anomalous red, anomalous blue, anomalous green anomalous NIR or no-data.